# How to group similar value from key value pair

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am getting following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 472
            [userId] => 570
            [docTypeId] => 2
            [trNo] => 1

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 479
            [userId] => 570
            [docTypeId] => 8
            [trNo] => 2

        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 479
            [userId] => 570
            [docTypeId] => 8
            [trNo] => 1

        )
```

What I want is based on same `[trNo]` there should be one tab and if `trNo` is different then it should generate another tab. Simply for similar value of `trNo` there should be one tab.

I used foreach loop to check similar value like:

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <?php 

        foreach($array as $userdet){


            if($array->trNo == 1)
            {
        ?>

            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">My Detail</a></li>

        <?php } else {
other condition

    }

        ?>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

What currently happening is as you can see there are two `trNo`with `1` so, it generating two tabs. Please Help me for this

Answer (score 1):

try this

Set some varible and increment it

```
$m = 0;

foreach($array as $userdet){

 if($userdet->trNo == 1 && $m == 0 ){

 $m++;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$array->trNo == 1
```

to

```
$userdet->trNo == 1
```

and it should work if you only have 1 or 2 in trNo. Otherwise you need to check if the trNo is a new one or has come earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried like this. You may help.
This is only for static value for `trNo`.

```
<?php
$array = array(array('id'=>472,'userId'=>570,'docTypeId'=>2,'trNo'=>1),array('id'=>479,'userId'=>570,'docTypeId'=>8,'trNo'=>2),array('id'=>479,'userId'=>570,'docTypeId'=>8,'trNo'=>1));
?>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <?php 
        $tab = '';
        foreach($array as $userdet)
        {           
            if($userdet['trNo'] == 1 && $tab != $userdet['trNo'])
            { ?>
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">My Detail</a></li>
            <?php 
            $tab = $userdet['trNo'];
            } 
            else
            { 
                if($tab == $userdet['trNo'])
                {
                    continue;
                }
             ?>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
            <?php   
            }

           }?>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Always add explanation with every answer that you post.  Treat SO like a classroom.